# NServiceBus log4Net appender

Tags: nservicebus

I am having a problem with custom logging with NServiceBus.

I have set up the Configuration as described and when I get my logger the appender list is null.  Has anyone any ideas on what I am missing/doing wrong?

Cheers

My endpoint is:

```
public void Init()
        {
            SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure);

            Configure.With().DisableTimeoutManager();


        }
```

My app.config:

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>

 <log4net>
    <appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
      <threshold value="DEBUG"/>
      <to value="test@test.com" />
      <from value="test@test.com" />
      <subject value="Error" />
      <smtpHost value="localhost" />
      <bufferSize value="512" />
      <lossy value="false" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] &lt;%X{auth}&gt; - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: Does adding .Log4Net() to your Configuration help? It probably should read Configure.With().Log4Net().DisableTimeoutManager();

Comment: do you really want an email every time nservicebus logs debug?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I have just changed my logging to use NLog as I feel it is a much nicer logging framework than log4net in terms of Configuration.  Dave, the debug was just for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (assuming you are using `AsA_Server` as the endpoint role otherwise change it):

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server, IWantCustomLogging
{
    public void Init()
    {
        NServiceBus.SetLoggingLibrary.Log4Net(log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure);

        Configure.With()
                   .DisableTimeoutManager();
    }
}
```

For more info see [this sample project](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/tree/master/Samples/GenericHost/LoggingFromAppConfig)